# Keras predict function throws AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am following this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/phoenix120/lstm-sentence-embeddings-with-additional-features) to train rnn classifier on small dataset to check if the code is working.

While running command
`rnn.predict(data_test, 'answer.csv')`, throws exception:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Here is the predict function

```
def predict(self, data_test, answer_filename):
    word_matrix, char_matrix, additional_features_matrix = data_test

    print("Test example: ")
    print(word_matrix[0])
    print(char_matrix[0])
    print(additional_features_matrix[0])
    preds = self.model.predict([word_matrix, char_matrix, additional_features_matrix], 
                               batch_size=self.batch_size, verbose=1)
    index_to_author = { 0: "EAP", 1: "HPL", 2: "MWS" }
    submission = pd.DataFrame({"id": test["id"], index_to_author[0]: preds[:, 0], 
                               index_to_author[1]: preds[:, 1], index_to_author[2]: preds[:, 2]})
    submission.to_csv(answer_filename, index=False)
```

The `word_matrix`, `char_matrix`, `additional_features_matrix` are of variable length. In my case, the dimensions are (80,), (80, 30) and (1153, 15) respectively. I google it and found that I should add padding to the input numpy array.

But, the code in the link worked fine. I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the details about your input `data_test`? Maybe the relevant coe where you call predict.

Comment: rnn = SpookyRNN()
rnn.load(MODEL_FILENAME)
rnn.predict(data_test, 'answer.csv')

It throws error at the last statement.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Also, you still didn't include where `data_test` is coming from. Also, three lines of code that simply construct a network is quite a stretch to work on, so maybe add some more lines that show how you compile the model, what optimizer you use, where you call fit, ... (assuming you are using Keras)

Answer (score 1):

I found out my own mistake. If you follow this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/phoenix120/lstm-sentence-embeddings-with-additional-features) then you will find the following line of code:

`_, additional_features_matrix_test = collect_additional_features(x.iloc[idx_train], x_test)`

The function `collect_additional_features` returns a tuple of two ndarrays. My mistake was that I missed `_` and hence the line of code became:

```
additional_features_matrix_test = collect_additional_features(x.iloc[idx_train], x_test)
```

Thus the `additional_features_matrix_test` became a tuple instead of an ndarray and while passing the `additional_features_matrix_test` to the LSTM it threw the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'`